# Create MS-Word table with Powerpoint slide info using a loop

Tags: vba, ms-word, powerpoint

What is causing my PowerPoint VBA macro to stop working when I add a 'For Each' loop to create a table in Word with slide info?

PowerPoint VBA Macro works for one slide, breaks when For Each loop added

I have a macro that runs in PPT that creates a table in Word with the slide number, a thumbnail image of the slide, and the slide notes in a one row table. I have it working for one slide, but when I added a `For Each sdl in ActivePresentation.Slides` it stopped working even for one slide.

I get a Compile error: Method or data member not found that points to sld.Copy (I've surrounded it in ******* in the block that follows).

This version includes the loop:

```
Sub CreateScriptTableLoop()

    Dim sld As Slides
    Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides
    
    ' Set up Word
    
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
    
        Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
        If wdApp Is Nothing Then Set wdApp = New Word.Application
        Set wdDoc = wdApp.ActiveDocument
        
    ' Start loop
    
    Debug.Print "Start Loop"
    
    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    
    ' Set up Table
    
    ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=3
    
    Debug.Print "Table created"
    
    ' Get Slide Number and put in column 1
    
    Dim oshp As Shape
    
    With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes
    
    Set oshp = .AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 100, 100, 40, 20)
        oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.InsertSlideNumber
        oshp.Name = "Slide Num"
    
    End With
    
    ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Slide Num").TextFrame.TextRange.Copy
        
    With ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(Row:=1, Column:=1).Range
        .Borders.OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
        .PasteAndFormat wdFormatPlainText
        
    End With
    
    ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Slide Num").Delete
    
    Debug.Print "Slide number inserted"
    
    ' Get thumbnail and put in column 2
    
    
    '*************************************************************
    sld.Copy
    
    '*************************************************************
    
    Set mySlideCopy = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Paste
    
    With mySlideCopy
    
      .Name = "Slide Thumbnail"
      .Left = 0
      .Top = 0
      .Height = 400
      .Width = 400
     
    End With
    
    ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Slide Thumbnail").Copy
    
    Debug.Print "Thumbnail copied"
    
    With ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(Row:=1, Column:=2).Range
        .Borders.OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
        .PasteAndFormat wdPasteDefault
    End With
    
    ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Slide Thumbnail").Delete
    
    Debug.Print "Thumbnail pasted"
    
    'Get notes and put in column 3
    
    sld.NotesPage.Shapes.Placeholders(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Copy
    
    With ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(Row:=1, Column:=3).Range
        .Borders.OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
        .PasteAndFormat wdFormatPlainText
    End With
    
    Debug.Print "Notes Pasted"
    
    Next sld
    
    Debug.Print "Done"


End Sub
```

Any pointers greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:
The problem above is that it treats Slides as a single slide when in fact it's an array of all slides. To fix it, I created:

`Dim sld As Slide`

`Dim sldS As Slides`

`Set sldS = ActivePresentation.Slides`

And changed the start of the loop to:

`For Each sld In sldS`

BUT!
The approach I used above (using copy and paste to move content between PPT and Word) has proven to be a VERY BAD IDEA.

When testing on moderately sized decks, notes or slide numbers would randomly find their way to the wrong place in the table, or an image would be pasted as text, or text as an image, and it would crash. I'm now rewriting the macro the ground up to save things out to files and then import them into Word. It's much more complicated but, hopefully, will lead to better results.

Comment: Because `sld`, being [`Slides`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slides), does not have a method or data member "Copy"? As opposed to [`Slide`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slide) that [does](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slide.copy)?

Comment: Try to use sld.Range.Copy

Comment: @GSerg is correct; DIMming sld as Slides makes it expect a SlideRange object. Change it to Dim sld as Slide and it'll likely work as expected.

Comment: Thanks, that put me on the right path. I ended up changing sld to `Dim sldS as Slides` and changing the loop to `For Each sld in sldS` and it now loops. [It doesn't put the content in the right place in the table, but that's another matter.]

Comment: @PMPM2000 So? Your problem is solved? Then I won't try again. Could you please state in the title or at the top of the content that it would be nice if you could share your solution so that people, later on, don't think the problem is still unsolved? `sld.Copy` maybe should be `sld.Range.Copy` ; `sld.NotesPage.Shapes.Placeholders(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Copy` be `sld.Range.NotesPage.Shapes.Placeholders(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Copy`  You should be clear that **Slides** and **SlideRange** (← **Slides.Range** ) are different things first. Or `Dim sld As Slides` should be `Dim sld As Slide` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why you add an object and then delete it, in many cases, it is not necessary. I just assume that you are doing the exercise, so I will keep your original code：

Let's try it out,  how about ?

```vb
Sub CreateScriptTableLoop()

    Dim sld As Slide, slideNumberNoteStr  As String, oshp As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim sldS As Slides, mySlideCopy As PowerPoint.ShapeRange
    
    Set sldS = ActivePresentation.Slides
    
    ' Set up Word
    
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim tb As Word.Table, ur As Word.UndoRecord, r As Long
    
        On Error GoTo eH:
        Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
        'If wdApp Is Nothing Then Set wdApp = New Word.Application
        If wdApp.Documents.Count = 0 Then wdApp.Documents.Add
        Set wdDoc = wdApp.ActiveDocument
        Set ur = wdApp.UndoRecord
        ur.StartCustomRecord "CreateScriptTableLoop"
        
        ' Set up Table
        
        'ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=3
        Set tb = wdDoc.Tables.Add(Range:=wdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=3)
        
        With tb.Borders
            .OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
            .InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
        End With
    
    ' Start loop
    
    Debug.Print "Start Loop"
    
    For Each sld In sldS 'For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    
        r = r + 1
        If r > 1 Then tb.Rows.Add
        
        Debug.Print "Table created"
        
        ' Get Slide Number and put in column 1
        
        
        'With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes
        With sld.Shapes
            
            Set oshp = .AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 100, 100, 40, 20)
                slideNumberNoteStr = oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.InsertSlideNumber.Text
                oshp.Name = "Slide Num"
        
        End With
        
        'ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Slide Num").TextFrame.TextRange.Copy
'        sld.Shapes("Slide Num").TextFrame.TextRange.Copy
            
        'With ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(Row:=1, Column:=1).Range
        With tb.Cell(Row:=r, Column:=1).Range
'            .Borders.OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
            '.PasteAndFormat wdFormatPlainText
            .Text = slideNumberNoteStr
        End With
        
'        ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Slide Num").Delete
        sld.Shapes("Slide Num").Delete
        
        Debug.Print "Slide number inserted"
        
        ' Get thumbnail and put in column 2
        
        
        '*************************************************************
        sld.Copy
        
        '*************************************************************
        
        'Set mySlideCopy = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Paste
'        Set mySlideCopy = sld.Shapes.Paste
        
'        With mySlideCopy
'
'          .Name = "Slide Thumbnail"
'          .Left = 0
'          .Top = 0
'          .Height = 400
'          .Width = 400
         
'        End With
        
        'ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Slide Thumbnail").Copy
'        sld.Shapes("Slide Thumbnail").Copy
        
        Debug.Print "Thumbnail copied"
        
        'With ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(Row:=1, Column:=2).Range
        With tb.Cell(Row:=r, Column:=2).Range
'            .Borders.OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
            .PasteAndFormat wdPasteDefault
        End With
        
        'ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Slide Thumbnail").Delete
'        sld.Shapes("Slide Thumbnail").Delete
        
        Debug.Print "Thumbnail pasted"
        
        'Get notes and put in column 3
        
        'sld.NotesPage.Shapes.Placeholders(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Copy
        slideNumberNoteStr = sld.NotesPage.Shapes.Placeholders(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text
        
        'With ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(Row:=1, Column:=3).Range
        With tb.Cell(Row:=r, Column:=3).Range
'            .Borders.OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
            '.PasteAndFormat wdFormatPlainText
            .Text = slideNumberNoteStr
        End With
        
        Debug.Print "Notes Pasted"
        
    Next sld
    
    Debug.Print "Done"

exitSub:
    Set wdApp = Nothing
    ur.EndCustomRecord
    
Exit Sub


eH:
Select Case Err.Number
    Case 429 'ActiveX component cannot generate object
        Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        'wdApp.UserControl = True
        wdApp.Visible = True
        wdApp.Activate
        Resume Next
    Case Else
        MsgBox Err.Number + Err.Description
'        Resume ' just for test
        GoTo exitSub
End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @oscar-sun! This is a huge improvement. I'll need to sit down and spend some time to really understand the changes, but you've taken it a big step forward.

Comment: @PMPM2000 Good! Keep going.